# How to set the condition in my if statement, if the user has to type in a whole number? C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
//Hold the Roses' cost
decimal numberofRoses;//user's desired number of roses
decimal totalCostofRoses; //the total amount of the roses' price
const decimal COST_PER_ROSE = 10;//each rose cost 10 dollars

//Get the user's input
numberofRoses = decimal.Parse(rosesTextBox.Text);

if ()//Require a condition where the user has to type in a whole number
{

}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please input a whole number for the number of roses");
}
```

Comment: use a numericupdown set to 0 decimals, or just see of the text `.Contains()` the local decimal character

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you try google next time ? and [read this](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) please.

Comment: yeah sorry about this I tried google I couldn't find the answer I was looking for. every program has different ways to set the condition. thanks for these comments though, sorry if I made a group of pro programmers angry lol...

Comment: @BlueRay I don't think you made anyone angry, it's just that the best part of programming, at least to me, is the excitement of solving a puzzle.  When you ask such a very basic question, that appears to be part of school work, without doing much research (it's apparent, because there are a ton of resources on the subject), it makes one question if you're heading down the right path, if you catch my drift.

Comment: @B.K. I love your comment. As programmer, we are just riddle player and we love it.

Comment: In the future, googling **how to check if a string is an integer c#**, which is exactly what you want to do, should get you [to this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752499/c-sharp-testing-to-see-if-a-string-is-an-integer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide it by 1 and if the remainder is 0, it is a whole number:

```
if ((numberofRoses % 1) == 0) 
{

}
```

You can also parse the number as an `int` using [Int32.TryParse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which would be more effective:

```
int roses = 0;
if (int.TryParse(numberofRoses, out roses)
{
    //"roses" is now an int (Whole number)
}
```

Comment: How silly of me to forget that to a whole number's reminder has to be zero... thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

```
int num; // use a int not a decimal. You dont want half of a rose.
if (Int32.TryParse(rosesTextBox.Text, out num)
{
    // do something with num. it is an int.
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please input a whole number for the number of roses");
}
```

Comment: I have not yet learn what Int32 does and what's its purpose. However this condition works. I'm going to use the less advance method to determine if the user input has to be a whole number. Great answer though thanks.