# validate the input of a string as an integer value using c#?

Tags: c#

I have the following code, what i do is the following:
I enter a string of numbers with the following format and what I do is debug and adopt the correct format, example:
correct format: XXXX/XX

```
456/12  = 0456/12  
25/1    = 0025/01
1/23    = 0001/23
/       = 0000/00
```

but what I don't take into account is that if what enters is an intger or not, if it is an integer it accepts it but it rejects it.
for example:

```
A324/1   =  FORMAT ERROR
458/P8   = FORMAT ERROR
```

How to solve this problem?

my code:

```
 public static string Validate_Cc(string CourtCase)
        {
           // int i = 0;
            string[] parts = CourtCase.Split('/');
            var number1 = Int32.Parse(parts[0]);
            var number2 = Int32.Parse(parts[1]);

            if ((CourtCase.Length) > 7)
            {
                 badLines(CourtCase);
            }
         
             return $"{number1:0000}/{number2:00}";
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# testing to see if a string is an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752499/c-sharp-testing-to-see-if-a-string-is-an-integer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`int.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0) instead of `Int32.Parse`

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the operation succeeded.

```
//I updated condition as well as variable names as per the .net naming convensions
public static string Validate_Cc(string courtCase)
{
    string[] parts = courtCase.Split('/')
           .Select(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) ? "0" : x) //To handle "/" edge case
           .ToArray();

    if(int.TryParse(parts[0], out int number1) && int.TryParse(parts[1], out int number2))
        return $"{number1:0000}/{number2:00}";          
    else
        return BadLines(courtCase);
}
```

---

[Try online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AZSyRg)

Comment: i use `int.Parse()`, when i use `int.TryPase()` it generates an error.

Comment: What is an error?

Comment: @JuanSastre, I updated my code to make it more clear, kindly take a look

Comment: thansk for your support, i have tried to execute your code but I get a syntax error in: `return badLines(courtCase);` because it cannot convert a void type to string

Comment: method badlines: `public static void badLines (string baditem){....}`

Comment: @JuanSastre, did you get chance to look into the [live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AZSyRg) which I added in my answer. To fix BadLines() method issue please read about [return types in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/return-type?view=msvc-160)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
public static string Validate_Cc(string CourtCase)
    {
    string[] parts = CourtCase.Split('/');
    if(parts.Length != 2)
    {
        badLines(CourtCase);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
    {
        if(parts[i] == "")
        {
            parts[i] = "0";
        }
    }
    var isValidInput = int.TryParse(parts[0], out int number1) & int.TryParse(parts[1], out int number2);
    if(!isValidInput) 
    {
        badLines(CourtCase);
        return input;
    }
   
    return $"{number1:0000}/{number2:00}";
    }
```

First, you check whether there is an `/` in your string by checking the length of `parts`. Then you replace empty string with `"0"`. Make sure that the second `TryParse` is executed by using the `&` operator.

Comment: thanks for your support, i have run your code and it works fine but there is a small nuance: for example, `A45/25` should not be set to `0000/25`. i should just ignore it and report it in the `badLines()`.. for other cases that are numeric: `25/02 -> 0025/02` it would be correct to apply format.

Comment: @JuanSastre But your method has to return something. What do you want to return if it is an invalid input?

Comment: if it's an invalid entry, i return that input value in a csv file which is the `badLines(string baditem)`, this method generates a csv with those invalid entries so it's easier to locate them and correct their format based on other parameters.

Comment: i mean that i return the same value:   `A234/3 -> A234/3` or `AP1/3 -> AP1/3` ... return the same value, but reports the issue that it is not an integer string via `badLines()`

Comment: @JuanSastre This can be done quite easily. Just add `return input` inside the if clause after calling `badLines`. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking pattern with regex and then parsing:

```
private static string ParseCourtCase(string courtCase)
{
    if(!Regex.Match(courtCase, @"\d+\/\d+").Success)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Incorrect format of input string.");
    }

    var parts = courtCase.Split('/');
    var number1 = int.Parse(parts[0]);
    var number2 = int.Parse(parts[1]);

    return $"{number1:0000}/{number2:00}";
}
```