# C# datatable linq receiving mode 3 this ushort variable "Mins"

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I've written a linq command that makes the mins variable go three, but I'm getting an `InvalidCastException`. Does this command work without the `System.Data.DataSetExtension.dll`?

I can't add this reference because this is already exists but there is no this dll. Thanks

This is my code:

```
dataTable = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                     .Where(x => x.Field<int>("Mins") % 3 == 0)
                     .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: try `Convert.ToInt32(x["Mins"])`

Comment: this works but it shows .3 too, skip and every dont work

Comment: your requirement never states the how to filter numbers. i only see `InvalidCastException`

Comment: Exception is solved thanks but as i say it shows ".3" too how can i skip this values

Comment: We really need to know the type of the `Mins` column in the table. And please stick to a single question per post, making sure you specify it as clearly as possible.

Comment: it has ushort values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me clarify your requirement: You want filter the rows that the column `Mins`

1. has only integer value
2. is a multiply of 3.

```cs
        static DataTable GenerateTestTable(string[] nums)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Mins");
            foreach (string num in nums)
            {
                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                row[0] = num;
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            return dt;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = GenerateTestTable(new string[] { "1", "3", ".3" });
            int n;
            dt = dt.AsEnumerable()
                   .Where(x => int.TryParse(x["Mins"].ToString(), out n)
                            && n % 3 == 0)
                   .CopyToDataTable();
            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(r[0]);
            }
            //only outputs 3
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Seems `.Where(x => Convert.ToDouble(x["Mins"]) % 3 == 0)` works too. But I still prefer checking int first, because I'm never confident of result of `double %` .

*reference*

[C# testing to see if a string is an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1752505/1518100)

[Field(DataRow, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowextensions.field?view=net-6.0#system-data-datarowextensions-field-1(system-data-datarow-system-string))

Comment: there is a same bug

Comment: see my entire code, just copy and run.

Comment: Convert.ToDouble() is worked thanks god bless you

Comment: `int.TryParse` should also work. please try the latest code.